# Best similarity measure for strings with shifted blocks

Tags: c#, algorithm, diff, string-comparison

I'm comparing strings to compute similarity between them. Initially I went for "Levenshtein Distance" algorithm, but it now turns out that it is not the best algorithm for the kind of input I have. My input strings can undergo **block-move** operations, which results in large Levenshtein distance between very similar string. Here is an example of two string that have large edit distance, but are essentially similar:

> ## First version
>
> Q: Pick your favorite breed:
>
> 1. German Shephard
> 2. Dalmation
> 3. Colly
> 4. Rottweiler
> 5. Great Dane
>
> ## Second version
>
> Q: Which of the following breed is your favorite:
>
> 1. Colly
> 2. Dalmation
> 3. German Shephard
> 4. Great Dane
> 5. Rottweiler

I then checked for the diff utility that is used by GIT, which IIRC uses Myers algorithm, but GIT too suffers from the problem that it can't detect block shifts and considers them as two delete and insert operations.

Which other algorithm do I have that would give me smaller distances for strings that are **qualitatively** similar but might have large edit distances? Even better if an implementation in C#, VB.NET, C++ or Java is available so that I could port it.

Note: **Qualitative** does not mean any kind of *intelligent* content analysis. It would still be objective, but should just consider block moves to be one operation rather than N operations, where N is the number characters in the block.

Comment: If large portions of the text would remain unchanged, I could imagine using the diff algorithm as a base, then compare these insert/deletes separately to identify them as a move. That should work for code blocks, but I can imagine not for other types of data.